# not able to run maven project

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

I have a maven project, where in src/test/java i have a java file which have @Test method, which basically initiates the entire test suite and when i run through TestNG or jUnit everything works fine.

But when i run this by Maven Test, i am getting below message and nothing executes. Can someone help me in this?

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for MavenHybridFramework:MavenHybridFramework:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.relevantcodes:extentreports:jar should use a variable instead of a hard-coded path D:\UD\jars\extentreports_Updated.jar @ line 36, column 18
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.monte:media:jar should use a variable instead of a hard-coded path D:\UD\jars\MonteScreenRecorder.jar @ line 43, column 18
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MavenHybridFramework 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ MavenHybridFramework ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ MavenHybridFramework ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ MavenHybridFramework ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ MavenHybridFramework ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ MavenHybridFramework ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.491 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-23T09:35:28+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/17M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Following is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MavenHybridFramework</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenHybridFramework</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.47.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>1.41</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>D:\UD\jars\extentreports_Updated.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.monte</groupId>
        <artifactId>media</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.7</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>D:\UD\jars\MonteScreenRecorder.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Following is my TestNG test

```
package TestSuite;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import FrameworkLibraries.FunctionLibraries.CommonFunctionLibrary;
import FrameworkLibraries.FunctionLibraries.FrameworkFunctionLibrary;

public class AutomationDriver 
{

    @Test
    public void runTestSuite()
    {
        FrameworkFunctionLibrary frameworkFuncLib=new FrameworkFunctionLibrary();

        //The below method initilizes the framework to make sure required configurations exists
        frameworkFuncLib.frameworkInit();

        //The below loads the required Test Data configurations and execute test cases
        frameworkFuncLib.frameworkExecuteTestCases();
    }   
}
```

Comment: which is the maven cmd You use?

Comment: I use eclipse, so i right click on the project and choosen run as -> Maven Test

Comment: @Uday please update your question with new error on command prompt and also  try my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a Maven Clean first.
Then try executing the Maven Test.

Also, Eclipse Maven integration doesn't work always.
Try executing mvn clean install from the Command Prompt/Shell.

This should work.

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project MavenHybridFramework: Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\..\lib\tools.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Comment: You should be using JDK rather than JRE.

Comment: Melvins, can you please help where i need to configure this JDK?

Comment: JAVA_HOME should point to JDK, example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45 rather than a JRE.

Comment: Melvins, my jdk points  to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25 in my JAVA_HOME environmental variables.

Comment: Then make sure this is the java used while executing the mvn cmd. Because from the earlier snapshot of error You have posted, it clearly picks from the JRE.

Comment: not yet melvins. Tried all the other options which i found in internet but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

For following error,

`Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\..\lib\tools.jar ->`

Add this:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath> add your path/Java/jdk1.7.0_60/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: I added following dependency,  <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.0</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
   </dependency> getting the same error. my java_home points to C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25 only

Comment: Yes, i can able to see in maven dependencies folder.

Comment: BTW, i tried creating a new project with very simple code and it is working fine. Does it is because of the warning message(from my above post) it is not able to build

Comment: I don't think its because of warning, you should get something like this Results :
'Running yourpackage.TestClass

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0'

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below to pom.xml. It should enhance the compiler version to JDK 1.8 . For me, it worked.

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```